# Failed to play sound: Invalid state

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, audio, pipewire

I'm running on Arch Linux with gnome and Pipewire.

I have the strange issue, that when I want to play sound I get the following error message:

```
(gnome-control-center:4636): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: 12:13:50.653: Failed to play sound: Invalid state
```

I found this in `journalctl` when trying to run a speaker test through sound settings and also got it printed when running `gnome-control-center` via CLI and running speaker test from there.

Side effect: I cannot e.g. start any YouTube videos, they just do not play, unless I open `pavu control` go to `configuration` and swap my profile to anything and back to my current state (`Analog Stereo Duplex`). After that dance audio works fine and I can play YouTube videos.

Maybe unrelated, but my internal microfone is dysfunctional, too. I always need to use the BlueTooth mic from my headset, even the USB mic form my webcam does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to debug this? To be honest, I don't even know where to start.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I m fedora user so my advise can be wrong but nobody answered you so:
i use comand: `sudo dnf install libcanberra-devel-0.30-31.fc38.x86_64`
and thats fix everything so meybe try that
good luck!